# Replacing Kitchen Faucet - Unable to disconnect

Tags: faucet

I am installing a new kitchen faucet, and to disconnect my old one I came across a type of connection for which I am unsure how to disconnect.

Can someone help me identify what kind of connection this is, and how to properly disconnect it?

[image: Plumbing connections]

Comment: Think they might be quick disconnects.  The plastic ring is a locking mechanizium and you need to push/pull on the plastic to unlock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those go by a few names, but they are quick connect/push to fit connections.  To release them, you have to push on the connector like you are trying to make it seal, and then push the piece of plastic towards the brass part.  The fitting has little teeth inside that grip the pipe.  Pushing the whole fitting onto the pipe loosens the teeth and then compressing the plastic ring releases the teeth.

Then it should just slide off.  You may need to rotate it slightly to get it to start moving.  Just to reiterate, the plastic ring gets compressed towards the brass part.  It looks like the broken one may have been pried on the wrong way.

For the one with the damaged plastic ring...  You will most likely just have to cut that off.  The plastic ring releases a ring of teeth, and they all have to be released at the same time so you need a solid ring to push against.  You *might* be able to push whats left of the plastic ring with a few screwdrivers and a helper, but its going to be a challenge.  Since you're changing the faucet anyway, maybe cutting isn't that bad of an option.

Comment: For the missing ring just cut the black hose with scissors